# Using Expando object with RazorEngine throws error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting params list from post and creating IDictionaryObj in which i store this. In Debug mode i can see all the key/values that i pass in, they appear as properties of this expando object. However, when i pass that object to RazorEngine's parse method, it complains that any of the provided properties are not there. What am i doing wrong here?

```
        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();

        var templateModel = expando as IDictionary<String, object>;

        templateModel["To"] = email.To;
        templateModel["From"] = email.From;
        templateModel["Message"] = email.Body;

        var templateData = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(extraParams);

        foreach (var property in templateData.AllKeys)
        {
            templateModel[property] = templateData[property];
        }

        var mailBody = Razor.Parse(template, templateModel.ToExpando());
```

Last line throws following error:

'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'From'

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that your code is good for the `.ToExpando()`, you are probably missing Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: It wouldn't even compile if that were to be the issue here.

Comment: You may want reasearch extension methods and their requirements for usage in other areas of an application.   Also, you should post more code.

Answer (score -1):

You have not shown the variable template.

When using ExpandoObject in RazorEngine you need to ensure your template does not have @model even if @model points to ExpandoObject or you will get this exception.

If you have @model in your template you need to remove it.